# Can I add already created pages to tab control?

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I have a tab control with tabs on it in a windows application. I have already created some pages. Can I make these pages display on tabs of the tab control?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by *created some pages* ?

Comment: Have you tried actually adding them? `myTabControl.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);`. Also [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpages.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

edit:

To add forms to a TabControl, you will first want to set a Panel inside of a page in the TabControl. Then, do the following in the constructor of the form with the TabControl:

```
FormToLoad formToLoad = new FormToLoad();
formToLoad.TopLevel = false;
panelInTabPage.Controls.Add(formToLoad);
formToLoad.Show();
```

You may also want to individually style your forms so that they don't show window chrome.

Comment: i will try to make it more clear.... i have created some pages in my windows application now requirement has changed .Now i have to display pages on tab control as tab pages. My question is that Is there ne way to make my page with .cs extention diplay on tab.

Comment: @mubashir Does your meaning of pages mean a Window `Form` ?

Comment: @mubashir I edited my response. See if my new answer works for you.

Comment: Thanks from the depth of my heart I love stack overflow

Comment: @mubashir My pleasure. Since this is your first question, make sure to mark my answer as accepted if it solved things for you.

Comment: Another problem has arised I display forms from menu also now when tab control is there I m not able to display some forms which are not in tabs

Comment: @mubashirGul9082 I'd suggest starting another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Make Usercontrols of your pages and add them as TabPages

Comment: Another problem has arised I display forms from menu also now when tab control is there I m not able to display some forms which are not in tabs.